# GWT deploy Project on Webserver RPC

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I made a little webapp : where i have Button when I click on it, it will get VIA RPC data from my MySQL DB.

I did following steps :

1 . Compile

2 . war folder -> in my Webhoster VIA fileZila

I tried a

```
Window.alert (result.toString());
```

to see if i ever get a RPC onSucces but i dont, which means RPC never worked

Comment: Is there any exception logged? Try it first with sample project without any database related codes. Without sample code we can't analysis it. Please share some code.

Comment: Is your webhoster's domain and your RPC-server's domain the same (including port number, etc.)?

Comment: i got it!my free Webhoster didnt have JAVA on server sided.